# Could Absolute Zero Stop an Electron Beam?

Tags: electrons, molecules

**Context:**

Okay, I have a comic book scenario and I want to know what would happen.

- Fighter A can forcibly control electrons in the state of an electron where it is both particle and wave, and when they strike other objects the electrons are unable to react either as particle or a wave because of their state. Normally, electrons have a mass that is close to zero, but because they are "stopped" at this state they take become like a solid object. This then creates a highly destructive beam of very fast electrons that pierces through a target at the same velocity that it was fired.
- Fighter B is able to drop temperature to absolute zero (the point where all molecular motion stops).

Which power would negate the other?

**Physics:**

I have two questions about the scenario described above,

1. Is the idea that electrons can be stopped "in the middle" of each of their states (wave and particle) and that makes them like a solid object at all realistic?
2. Can absolute zero stop the movement of electrons, or solid electrons like those described above?

**Edit:**

Sorry for wasting your time. I am just 16 and not a physics major. Just asking a question that I thought could theoretically be answered. I asked on other sites but no one would answer. They all kept pointing me to here. Thanks for the -2. Now that I know the response I'll stop asking questions.

Comment: I'm afraid the premises/ontology/concepts of this question are comic book physics, which means that there isn't going to be a coherent answer from real physics.

Comment: @zeldredge the physics of electrons at near absolute zero is a physical concept and can thus be probed both theoretically and expermentally. The source of one's question doesnt have anything to do with the physics. They may well have also thought of this question on an acid trip or at a physics seminar.

Comment: Sorry for wasting you guy's time. I am just 16 not really a physics major. Just asking a question that could be theoretically answered. Thanks for the -2 anyways. I asked on other sites but no one would answer. They all kept pointing me to here. Now that I know the response I'll stop asking questions.

Comment: If you are thinking about physics, and the effects of absolute zero, and curious enough to post your question, that's okay by me. Don't let one question put you off, look at how other questions that get answers are written.

Comment: @KawaiiSamii, I edited your question to try to make it more readable - kept your original meaning, of course. It's an interesting question - unfortunate you can't find anywhere to ask it. One thing though - keep asking questions! Perhaps not like this one, but do as count_to_10 said - look at other questions, keep thinking about physics, and keep being curious. Don't let one question keep you from asking others.

Comment: For reference someone on [scifi.se] told this poster that [physics.se] was a good place for this question. My suspicion is that the question is about some kind of comic or comic-like superhero material. Which means that the advice was very bad indeed.

Comment: I would also advise you to keep asking questions. The misfortune that you had here is that you came to the wrong place. There is an art and a science to writing both comic books and good science fiction, but I am not sure that it's actually being discussed on the scifi stackexchange... over here we are dealing _exclusively_ with the _real_ behavior of _real_ matter, radiation and spacetime and your question simply doesn't meet the criteria for what we call _real_, which are very strict. Look at the help bubble of the voting button to see the criteria for votes, it's nothing personal.

Comment: Trying to pick out physics question is of little use when you are starting with underspecified and aphysical preconditions. Unless we know how the alleged powers work there is no way to guess how they interact and there is no way for either of them to work. It's fantasy and the only answer to the questions is "Whatever the plot demands."

Comment: Fighter B is able to drop the temperature... of _what_?

Comment: @jameslarge drop the temperature of itself, so that the electron beam of fighter A won't affect it. Try to keep up with the (comic book) plot  :)

Comment: @heather thank you for being humble and kind to this person. Though i dont see anything wrong with asking about low temperature physics.

Comment: @user122066, while I agree with some of the sentiments expressed, there is not really a need to call anyone jerks or to use abbreviations for...um...well, I'm guessing you know what I mean by that one. (I might also add, if you think this guy should have an answer, then write it. I might.)

Comment: @user122066, people will take you more seriously and will respect you if you respect them. That is why I commented.

Comment: @user122066 No system can be brought to absolute zero in finite time, nor be cooled below the local radiative environmental temperature without contact with the cooling system, nor are there systems that can 'forcibly control the state of an electron' in the arbitrary sense the OP is using. He got some bad advice when he was told to bring his question here, and the users of the site have judged *this content*. They have not judged the user because that's not how we do things here. And by judging content rather than people we create high value repositories of content.

Comment: To the people who put this on hold: Please put it off hold. I think the question at this point is pretty clear. While it is in the context of a comic book, right now it asks two questions related to physics. I also think it's pretty clear what he's asking (others do too, there is an answer).

Comment: Thank you Heather and dmckee. it is good not to allow name calling, and also to maintain the site's emphasis on real physics. I do think that at times people seeing a question that is not in some ways the best, do make sarcastic or otherwise pretty unprofessional comments. People ask because they want to learn something, usually, and when they are somewhat confused on the physics it's ok to judge and make them make the question right, but some people don't know. Let's try to keep it all helpful, professional, and still about real physics.

Comment: @heather Personally I think the question is still not realistic enough to make it on topic here.

Comment: Try http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

As regards the first question, if you read this article, it might make the difference between waves and particles clearer. [Double Slit Experiment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment)

> Can absolute zero stop the movement of electrons, or solid electrons like those described above?

This is an exerpt from [Wikipedia Absolute Zero](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero)

> The laws of thermodynamics dictate that absolute zero cannot be reached using only thermodynamic means, as the temperature of the substance being cooled approaches the temperature of the cooling agent asymptotically.

Sorry if you already know what asymptotically means, but just in case, it's like moving along a curved road that gets closer and closer to another almost  parallel road, without ever connecting to it.

> A system at absolute zero still possesses quantum mechanical zero-point energy, the energy of its ground state at absolute zero. The kinetic energy of the ground state cannot be removed.

So the particle will keep moving, however slowly and however low the temperature. This is a consequence of the [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) that says you can't simultaneously  know the position  and velocity of a particle.